# Vue 3 - Emitting primitive value doesn't trigger input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, emit

I faced an strange issue with Vue3 $emit. I was refactoring my own Vue2 "form-input" -component, which is basically an wrapper for rendering either text-input, (multi)select-option, textarea or any other basic input field.

This component used to bind value against v-model, so it was emitting input via "this.$emit('input', this.value)".

Since Vue 3 changed input to update:modelValue, I made this modification and additionally presented "Emits" -property-list to component. Everything was seemingly working...

But then I recognized that Vue-multiselect 3 (NPM package "vue-multiselect": "^3.0.0-alpha.2") was emitting primitive value, an integer number, which didn't trigger @input on parent-component.

```html
form-input.vue

<input v-if="resolveType === 'text' || resolveType === 'number' || resolveType === 'tel' || resolveType === 'email'"
             v-model="localValue"
             @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
/>

<multiselect v-model="localValue"
             class="full-width-tags"
             @update:model-value="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"
/>

// Please note that multiselects $event is an integer, I have checked this multiple times from console.log
```

... and when I'm listening for @input on parent component it seems "text"-type field triggers event-listener but multiselect doesn't. Only difference on these components is that multiselect is emitting primitive value (integer), while input is sending an event-object.

Could someone explain why event-object and primitive value are handled differently for @input , and how could I fix my multiselects emit so that it's emitting input? Currently I'm emitting both "update:modelValue" AND "input" -events one after another for multiselect, but I'm just wondering if there is easier way?

Comment: I did create a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-multi-select-demo-0tzm4?file=/src/components/MultiSelect2.vue It seems multi-select Vue 3 version works as expected also with numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it seems you have read the Vue 3 Migration Guide - particularly [the part about change of `v-model` on custom components](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html#overview) and changed your `form-input` to emit `update:modelValue` event instead of `input` event

**So why are you listening for updates on your `form-input` component with `@input` instead of `@update:modelValue` ?**

The only reason why the `@input` placed on your `form-input` component in the parent works, is because of [this change](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-on-native-modifier-removed.html#_3-x-syntax)

In short - because your component declares that it emits `update:modelValue` event (using `emits` option), every other event listener placed on it is directly bound to the root element of the component - native `<input>` in this case

This is not what you want. Just change `<form-input @input="..." />` to `<form-input @update:modelValue="..." />`